# Decomposing parts of an effect

Tags: regression, interpretation

I am new to data analysis. Apologies if anything below needs more clarity or if this is very simple.

I am curious about decomposing the relationship between a `y` and an `x`, but I want to know how a set of `z` variables affects the relationship and the `y`.

A store allows independent vendors to sell their goods outside of the store. Only one vendor is allowed per day and the store rotates through a list of 30 different vendors. The order is pretty random.

I have longitudinal data on each vendor's sales (`y`).

I have parameters (`x`s) about the vendor that I am using to correlate to `y`. An example is how many individuals operate the vendor's booth.

I am interested in how parameters (`z`s) outside of the vendor's control affect sales (`y`). An example would be whether the store is having a sale or the day of the week.

I am also interested in how the `x`s (staffing) and `z`s (store sale or day of week) interact.

What regression would allow me to (1) state what percent of vendor sales is explained by `staffing`, (2) what percent of vendor sales is explained by `store sale`, (3) what percent of vendor sales is explained by accounting for `staffing` and `store sale`, and (4) what percent of vendor sales is explained by `staffing` and `store sale` co-occurring.

When I turn my attention to another `z` (`day of week`) do I also include the previous `z` (`store sale`) or no?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever model you end up using (perhaps linear regression, perhaps something longitudinal or multilevel) my advice would be to think about and model the effect of your $x$ variables one at a time. Taking vendor staffing as an example...

When you regress vendor sales ($y$) on vendor staffing (say, $x_1$), there are two types of covariates you should consider from the $x$ list and the $z$ list:

1. Variables that cause both $y$ and $x_1$. These are called confounders, and it is important to include them in your regression. An example may be "day of the week", if the day of the week is likely to affect both how many people are working for the vendor that day and how much will be sold that day.
2. Variables that are caused by both $y$ and $x_1$. These are called colliders, and it is important to NOT include them in your regression. I can't think of a good example of a collider for your case, but you should be on the lookout for that.

You would then run the regression and obtain an estimate for the effect of $x_1$.

You would then go through that process of covariate selection for the regression of $x_2$ on $y$, estimate the effect of $x_2$, and so on.

I'm unsure about this being a task for longitudinal-data models, mainly because different vendors sell on different days. Your panel would only have one observation per time-period (the sales number for the vendor that was active that day), which sounds more like a time-series where you assume the vendors are exchangeable.

But if you suspect staffing and other $x$ variables affect the sales of different vendors differently, look into multilevel models. In that case, each vendor would be a "cluster", and each datapoint on their sales for a particular day would be the "units" inside that cluster.

Hope this helps.